# ERROR: Unmarshalled object is an unsupported type in camel XML file

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing, apache-camel

I am using below camel route.xml file. Without threadpool config and multicast config, it is working fine. I added thread and multicast config so that my @Handler method will be running in multiple threads to achieve parallel processing of incoming messages. But when I run it, I am getting below error while starting the application. Any Idea/Suggestion would be appreciable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <threadPoolProfile id="routerThreadPoolProfile"
        defaultProfile="true" poolSize="10" maxPoolSize="20" maxQueueSize="1000"
        allowCoreThreadTimeOut="false" rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns" />

        <route id="IncomingRoute">
            <from
                uri="ceh:eventTest?namespaceName=sourceUri" />
        <multicast parallelProcessing="true" executorServiceRef="routerThreadPoolProfile"> 
            <to uri="bean:{{processorname}}" />
            <log message="Message Body - ${body}" />
        </multicast>
        </route>    
</camelContext>
```

---

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[${artifactId}][SYSTEM][SYSTEM][EMPTY][EMPTY][2020-06-04 15:02:25][main][ERROR][SpringApplication:771] - Application startup failed
org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmarshalled object is an unsupported type: org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean -> org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean@1e1598e5
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:250) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:57) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:358) ~[spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900) ~[spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.0.16.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at com.els.galaxy.galaxy_remoteview_router_boot.RVRouterApplicationBoot.main(RVRouterApplicationBoot.java:55) [classes!/:1.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [galaxy-remoteview-router-today.jar:1.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [galaxy-remoteview-router-today.jar:1.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [galaxy-remoteview-router-today.jar:1.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [galaxy-remoteview-router-today.jar:1.2.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmarshalled object is an unsupported type: org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean -> org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean@1e1598e5
    at org.apache.camel.model.ModelHelper.loadRoutesDefinition(ModelHelper.java:190) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ModelHelper.loadRoutesDefinition(ModelHelper.java:152) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.loadRoutesDefinition(DefaultCamelContext.java:1034) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.loadXmlRoutes(RoutesCollector.java:281) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:142) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1]
    ... 23 more
[${artifactId}][SYSTEM][SYSTEM][EMPTY][EMPTY][2020-06-04 15:02:25][main][INFO ][AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:1006] - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1fdfafd2: startup date [Thu Jun 04 15:00:10 IST 2020]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7cf10a6f
[${artifactId}][SYSTEM][SYSTEM][EMPTY][EMPTY][2020-06-04 15:02:25][main][INFO ][DefaultLifecycleProcessor:369] - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
[${artifactId}][SYSTEM][SYSTEM][EMPTY][EMPTY][2020-06-04 15:02:25][main][INFO ][SpringCamelContext:3499] - Apache Camel 2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[${artifactId}][SYSTEM][SYSTEM][EMPTY][EMPTY][2020-06-04 15:02:26][main][INFO ][SpringCamelContext:3590] - Apache Camel 2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 
[${artifactId}][SYSTEM][SYSTEM][EMPTY][EMPTY][2020-06-04 15:02:26][main][INFO ][SpringCamelContext:3591] - Apache Camel 2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.047 seconds
```

Comment: Any update? I am also getting similar error.

Comment: @Arindam please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was because I was thinking I'm dynamically loading XML routes with

```
context.loadRoutesDefinition(new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

where `value` was a `String` containing the XML.

But actually I was loading Rest routes instead of XML:

```
context.loadRestDefinition(new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

So, after changing ...`Rest`... to ...`Routes`... everything started working. But before that the error was exactly of the same format.